# how do I take partial execution times in junit tests

Tags: java, junit

I'd like to know what were times of execution of different parts in my test , for example

```
@Test
public void HappyPathTest() {

        connectToServiceRemote();
        // take execution time of connectToServiceRemote();
        getData();
        // take execution time of getData()
        transformData();
        // take execution time of transformData()

}
```

What I currently do is to use ugly  `System.currentTimeMillis()` and printing the result to the standard output.

my questions are:

- is there  something in junit framework better than using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
- if not , how can I include the information calculated with `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the  results report of junit.

Comment: You do not mention taking time using `@Setup`, `@TearDown`, isn't this what you are needing..

Answer (score 1):

Library can be used for performance measurement:
http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html

Comment: Well , this is not what I'm asking, JUnit already tell me how long it took for my test to end. I'm asking about getting snapshots of the time taken inside the test methods.